# Aligning indexes in two consecutive sums

Tags: subscripts

I want to align the indexes in

```
$\sum\limits_{j\in P}\sum\limits_{i\in \overline{P}}F_{ji}$
```

[image]

Comment: Just include a phantom at the end of the first limit: `{j\in P\vphantom{\overline P}}`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `\bar{P}`, the overline is really ugly.